# Are the review queues broken?

Tags: discussion, bug, moderation, community

When looking at the top-bar button that is tagged as "Review queues –help improve the site" I get the impression that this thingy randomly changes its appearance.

1. The dot appearance
   My current understanding is that the fuller these queues become, the more urgent the system thinks things have to be reviewed and indicates that status with a red dot overlay.
   That seems to not work for me. 
   The dot appeared when there was nothing to review and the dot remained absent when in reality the queues were filling up. That does not only happen for the top-bar but also within the drop down menu. Indicator for needed activity is active yet the queue is empty (for me?).
2. "First post" and "Late answer" never showing up for review
   I noticed that on casual visits: post with new activity, answer is obviously spam from a newly registered or unregistered "user". No increase in views, no VtC, no downvote, no comment, no flags. Looks as if I was one of the first to spot this. Open Review, post does not come up. Why not? (Flagged the post manually)
3. Close votes not showing up for review
   This just happened now, but also not for the first time. A two hour old post gets a first VtC. So that should show up in my review queue? It doesn't:
   [image]

---

The post in question did eventually appear and I reviewed it. After more than two hours as shown in the picture, after writing this post. So it remains unclear to me now when the first VtC appeared and how long that took to show up then for me.

For that I would like some more explanation. How soon are posts entered into the queues? (My assumption was: "immediately".) Do others see a similar behaviour? (Or am I temp banned, filtered out radnomly, have messed up my browser setup, etc?)

Comment: The red dot indicates that a lot of posts are waiting for review, however some posts need multiple reviews (suggested edits, close votes), so *you* might have reviewed them all, but they need one more review to be completed and hence the red dot.

Comment: Do you mean "red dot indicates that a lot of posts are waiting for *[my]* review"? If indeed *not* and it indicates not action required from me but the whole community (I cannot force others to review, not nudge or even notify…) is this a general "failing health" indicator? I doubt that.

Comment: Despite your doubts, [this appears to be the case indeed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302093/353950)

Comment: OK. one issue explained.

Comment: If this is the question in point 3, the [timeline of the post](https://health.stackexchange.com/posts/16562/timeline) shows a [review queue](https://health.stackexchange.com/review/close/15266). (It seems that you do prefer not to drag attention to a specific post, but checking at least whether there is a review in the timeline and whether others have reviewed it could add some useful information which might help potential answerers.)

Comment: This post on Meta Stack Exchange is related to your last paragraph: [How long does it take for a question to appear in the reopen queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209143) It is about reopen review queue, but I assume it works for other queues similarly. It clearly says that the question does not appear in the queue sooner than 15 minutes after the event that triggered entering the queue.

Comment: @Martin For multiple reasons the attention thing was a goal. [This post](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/16562/11231) is the one from the screenshot.

Comment: @Martin - the timeline facility is new to me. How do you call up the timeline of a given question?

Comment: @ChrisRogers See here: [How to see questions time line?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24826) And maybe also: [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566).